# Alternative solution to this?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$\displaystyle a^{-\frac{2}{3}} = 9$$
I've solved it by multiplying the reciprocal but how do you solve it by taking $\frac{1}{a}$ to the power of $\frac{2}{3} = 9$ and so forth?

Answer (score 7):

Hint: Take it as $a^{\frac{2}{3}}=(1/3)^2$, then take square root on both sides, then cube both sides to finally obtain your answer.

Comment: Kugelblitz, may God bless you. Thanks

Comment: Upvote and accept the answer to show your support to the community! @Öronpropp No problem :)

Answer (score 6):

$$a^{-2/3}=9=3^2\implies a^{-2}=(3^2)^3=3^6\iff a^2=3^{-6}$$

Extract square root in both sides

Comment: Not satisfied with the answer

Comment: I want to solve it by using the form 1/a to the power of 2/3 = 9

Comment: @Öronpropp, $$\dfrac1{a^{2/3}}=9\iff a^{2/3}=3^{-2}\iff a^2=(3^{-2})^3$$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I love that when you stop having "single" numbers you stop using the $\implies$ symbol :) $a^2 = 3^{-6} \nRightarrow a = 3^{-3}$ in the same way as $(-1)^2 = 1^2 \nRightarrow -1 = 1$

Answer (score 3):

$$
\begin{align}
a^{-\frac 23}&=9\\
\frac 1{\left(a^{\frac 13}\right)^2}&=3^2\\
3a^{\frac 13}&=1\\
27a&=1\\
a&=\frac 1{27}\quad\blacksquare
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that $a>0$, you can use logs.

Apply $\log_3$ to both sides and get
$$
-\frac23 \log_3 a = 2
$$
which implies
$$
\log_3 a = -3
$$
and so $a=3^{-3}$.

Answer (score 1):

Using $(a^b)^c = a^{bc}$, we can get:

$$ a = a^1 = a^{\left(-{2\over 3}\right)\times \left(-{3\over 2}\right)} = \left({a^{-{2\over 3}}}\right)^{-{3\over 2}} = 9^{-{3\over 2}} = {1\over (\sqrt{9})^3} = {1\over 27}$$